# How to change default redirect URL of Laravel 5 Auth filter?

Tags: php, laravel-5

By default if I am not logged and I try visit this in browser:

```
http://localhost:8000/home
```

It redirect me to `http://localhost:8000/auth/login`

How can I change to redirect me to `http://localhost:8000/login`

Comment: just change in  handle method of Authenticate middleware with named route.

Answer (score 45):

I wanted to do the same thing in Laravel 5.5. Handling authentication has moved to `Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authenticate` which throws an `Illuminate\Auth\AuthenticationException`.

That exception is handled in `Illuminate\Foundation\Exceptions\Hander.php`, but you don't want to change the original vendor files, so you can overwrite it with your own project files by adding it to `App\Exceptions\Handler.php`.

To do this, add the following to the top of the `Handler` class in `App\Exceptions\Handler.php`:

```
use Illuminate\Auth\AuthenticationException;
```

And then add the following method, editing as necessary:

```
/**
 * Convert an authentication exception into an unauthenticated response.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @param  \Illuminate\Auth\AuthenticationException  $exception
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
protected function unauthenticated($request, AuthenticationException $exception)
{
    if ($request->expectsJson()) {
        return response()->json(['error' => 'Unauthenticated.'], 401);
    }

    return redirect()->guest('login'); //<----- Change this
}
```

Just change `return redirect()->guest('login');` to `return redirect()->guest(route('auth.login'));` or anything else.

I wanted to write this down because it took me more than 5 minutes to figure it out. Please drop me a line if you happened to find this in the docs because I couldn't.

Comment: 5 minutes? ...dude... everything will be at least 1 hour for me lol.

Comment: Do not change core files, this is a really bad idea and when composer runs an update all your changes will be over written

Comment: Awsome answer . +1

Comment: @twigg that's no core file. This is the exeption handler located at App\Exceptions\Handler. Nothing will be overwritten

Comment: What is the purpose of `return redirect()->guest('login');` rather than `return redirect('login');`?

Comment: @Inigo the guest method saves the current url as the 'intended' destination while it redirects unauthenticated users. after logging in the user will be returned to the intended url

Comment: Tip: if you have multiple auth guards (an 'admin' guard perhaps), and you want to redirect to a different login page, you can check which guards where checked (and failed) like so: `if (in_array('admin', $exception->guards())) { ... }`

Comment: Thanks, saved me having to figure this out!

Answer (score 31):

Just to extend @ultimate's answer:

1. You need to modify `App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate::handle()` method and change `auth/login` to `/login`.
2. Than you need to add `$loginPath` property to your `\App\Http\Controllers\Auth\AuthController` class. Why? See [Laravel source](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/22b248c48c6b094a51b9a8de8cd8fde56531db5b/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Auth/AuthenticatesAndRegistersUsers.php#L135).

In result you'll have this in your middleware:

```
namespace App\Http\Middleware;
class Authenticate {
        /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if ($this->auth->guest())
        {
            if ($request->ajax())
            {
                return response('Unauthorized.', 401);
            }
            else
            {
                return redirect()->guest('/login'); // <--- note this
            }
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

And this in your AuthController:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;
class AuthController extends Controller
{
    protected $loginPath = '/login'; // <--- note this

    // ... other properties, constructor, traits, etc 
}
```

Comment: how i do this in modules middelware

Answer (score 11):

**This is Laravel 5.4 Solution:**

There is a new unauthenticated() method in app/Exceptions/Handler.php which handles unauthenticated users and redirects to login path.

So change

```
return redirect()->guest('login');
```

to

```
return redirect()->guest('auth/login');
```

Comment: Hi @salil i have error Sorry, the page you are looking for could not be found. NotFoundHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 161: when loading the custom login url. May i know how to solve this issue? do i need to create a new view just for the custom login?

Comment: Christ on a bike, this has changed yet again in Laravel 5.5. The `unauthenticated()` method is now removed from App/Exceptions/Handler.php. It's like with every version they want to obfuscate the inner workings of the authentication system further. Very frustrating for those of us wanting to modify- or even just understand- it.

Comment: OK, Laravel 5.5 solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45340855/laravel-5-5-change-unauthenticated-login-redirect-url

Answer (score 5):

Authentication checks are made using middleware in Laravel 5.

And the middleware for auth is `App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate`.

So, you can change it in `handle` method of the middleware.

Answer (score 5):

In Laravel 5.6, go to app/Exceptions folder and open the Handler.php, add a new method that overrides the unauthenticated method like so:

```
protected function unauthenticated($request, AuthenticationException $exception)
{
    if($request->ajax())
    {
        return response([
            "message" => "Unauthenticated.",
            "data" => [],
        ],401);
    }

    return redirect()->to('/');
}
```

This method is triggered when you access a protected route using the built-in "auth" middleware. Now you will have full control where to redirect or the response sent.

Answer (score 3):

EDIT: On Laravel 5.1, simply add **protected $redirectPath = '/url/you/want';** to AuthController would do the trick.

REFER : http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/authentication#included-authenticating

---

On Laravel 5.1, it is completely moved to another middleware named **RedirectIfAuthenticated.php** under **App\Http\Middleware**

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)

{
    if ($this->auth->check()) {
        return redirect('/'); //change this part to anywhere you wish to be redirected to
    }

    return $next($request);
}
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

could you please outputs `php artisan route:list` please

You are right you can set the following attributes:

```
protected $loginPath = 'xxx';

protected $redirectPath = 'xxx';

protected $redirectAfterLogout = 'xxx';
```

Set this attribute to you `AuthController.php`

Answer (score 0):

Since your other [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32480064/how-to-use-a-config-property-to-change-laravels-login-path) was marked as duplicate..I will try to answer it here..

First you need to change your route like

```
<?php
Route::get(config('constants.cms_path') . '/login', [
    'as' => 'login',
    'uses' => 'Auth\AuthController@getLogin'
]);
```

In your blade..make sure you use named route in the Login url link like

```
{{ route('login') }}
```

In Middleware/Authenticate.php change the redirect guest to

```
return redirect()->guest(config('constants.cms_path') . '/login');
```

Answer (score 0):

To change the redirection after the login, you only have to go to app/Http/Controllers/Auth/LoginController.php and add that inside the class LoginController:

```
protected $redirectTo = '/redirect-url-here';
```

Same for redirection after a new users register, but in that case, on AuthController.php

Answer (score 0):

For Laravel 5.4 You can set protected $redirectTo = '/'; in LoginController.php FILE.
Or in RegistersUsers.php file you can

```
protected function registered(Request $request, $user)
{
    return redirect('tosomeRoute'); 
    //Note: This code will run when
    //The user has been registered
}
```