# Change the post login redirect path

Tags: laravel-5

I'm at a loss here.

I've setup the default install of laravel with the built in authentication. I changed the `home` route to be called `admin` instead. I've updated `RedirectIfAuthenticated.php` with this change.

Basically, all I want is for the user to be redirected to the index (`/`) page once logged in.

I've scoured google and tried adding `protected $redirectTo = '/'` or `protected $redirectPath = '/'` to `app/Http/Controllers/Auth/AuthController.php` and nothing seems to change the redirect.

If I change the `new RedirectResponse(url('/admin'));` to `new RedirectResponse(url('/'));` in `RedirectIfAuthenticated.php` then I get a redirect loop.

Comment: Please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28702372/how-to-change-default-redirect-url-of-laravel-5-auth-filter

Comment: @KhanShahrukh That is how to change the redirect _to_ the login page. I want to redirect the user _after_ they've logged in to the index page rather than the default `home` (which I've renamed to admin) page.

Comment: Are you angry over my comment, I asked because I feel it

Comment: @KhanShahrukh no not at all :) Thanks for the reply. I had come across that link in my previous searches. I think I've hit every SO or Laracast / Laravel book there is... :/

Comment: you should change return property_exists($this, 'redirectTo') ? $this->redirectTo : '/home'; in AuthenticatesAndRegistersUsers.php

Comment: That seems to result in the same default redirect.

Comment: Did you ever work this one out? I'm stuck with the same problem.

Answer (score 4):

Here's the answer. The user is redirected away from the login screen if already authenticated, and the destination is set in the middleware.

For example, the default login location is currently set to /home, but we’ll change it.

Edit the RedirectIfAuthenticated.php file located in the app/Http/Middleware directory. Change line #38 to what is below.

Change default logged in location
Line #38 should be

```
return new RedirectResponse('/home');
```

// Change it to

```
return new RedirectResponse('/admin/post');
```

... or wherever else you want the page to redirect to.

Answer (score 1):

Add

```
protected $redirectPath = '/dashboard';
```

in Controllers\Auth\AuthController

Answer (score 0):

Originally taken from [this Laracasts post](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/default-authentication-dynamic-redirect?page=1). You can edit the `authenticated` method from the `App\Http\Controllers\Auth\LoginController` accordingly.

In my case:

```
public function authenticated()
{
    $user = $this->getUser();

    if ($user && $user->isAdmin()) {
        $this->redirectTo = route('admin.users.index');

        return null;
    }
}
```

The `return null` line is because the `AuthenticateUsers` trait implements the `sendLoginResponse(Request $request)` method and it asks if the `authenticate` method returns something:

```
return $this->authenticated($request, $this->guard()->user())
            ?: redirect()->intended($this->redirectPath());
```

Or perform the redirect.

You can return nothing as well and it will have the same effect.