# Routing problems with Laravel 5 on BlueHost Shared Server

Tags: laravel

I am in the Beta stage of a Laravel 5.0 project using BlueHost as the server. I have not finalised the domain so I am using a temporary address as follows:

> IP Address/username

In a normal Laravel project the root URL is the domain name of the website and routing starts from there. However, in this environment, I have to adjust the route.php file. For instance, instead of the familiar

```
Route::get('/', 'WelcomeController@index');
```

I've had to do this:

```
Route::get('/username/', 'WelcomeController@index');
```

With the usual adjustment in the .htaccess to re-route everything to the `public` Laravel folder, I can use the temporary address and access the welcome page. However, when I start adding security with the Auth controller, the re-directs don't work. When accessing a secure URL, you are re-directed to `IP Address/auth/login` instead of `IP Address/username/auth/login`. In the .htaccess file in the public folder I've added:

```
RewriteBase /username/
```

with both slashes, but that doesn't help. Does anyone know how to set up a Laravel project with a secure area, secured by the Auth controller which has a URL that includes a second segment?

Comment: This answer looks very promising http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28702372/how-to-change-default-redirect-url-of-laravel-5-auth-filter

Comment: Have you tried using named routes along with a route prefix group? That may be what your after. If you need an example let me know.