# Authentication in Laravel 5: Redirect the visitor to different pages, depending on the user type?

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, laravel-5

What I've been trying is to have the `middleware` do different tasks, based on the user's type.

Here is a Route group.

```
Route::group(array('prefix' => 'api', 'middleware' => 'admin'), function () {
    Route::resource('animal', 'AnimalController');
    //Other resources
});
```

My `User` model has 2 types, which can be accessed by the following way.

```
$this->user()->user_type_id;
```

[Following this advice,](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28702372/how-to-change-default-redirect-url-of-laravel-5-auth-filter) I was trying this task, and the `handle` function in `App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate` looks like this right now.

```
 public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    if ($this->auth->guest()) {
        if ((Auth::user()->user_type_id == 2) {
            //If the user is of type 2, this will be triggered
            if ($request->ajax()) {
                return response('You are type 2.', 401);
            }
            //Maybe there are other libes here
        } else if ($request->ajax()) {
            return response('Unauthorized.', 401);
        } else {
            return redirect()->guest('auth/login');
        }
    }
    return $next($request);
}
```

I thought that this would lead the user of type 2 to get `response('You are type 2.', 401)`, when the user visits a URL prefixed by `api/animal`, but I saw a message `Unauthorized.` in the response.

Is it possible to have the authentication middleware work in such a way?
Any advice will be appreciated.

Comment: By default `App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate::class` is mapped as `auth` not `admin`, check if changing the middleware name in the route definition will change anything.

Comment: Thank you korun, yes and I actually changed it as I editted.

Answer (score 0):

```
if ($this->auth->guest()) {
    if ($request->ajax()) {
        return response('Unauthorized.', 401);
    } else {
        return redirect()->guest('auth/login');
    }
} else if ($this->user()->user_type_id == 2) {
    //If the user is of type 2, this will be triggered
    return response('You are type 2.', 401);
}
```

Try this.