# Laravel 5.5 change unauthenticated login redirect url

Tags: php, laravel, authentication

In `Laravel < 5.5` I could change this file `app/Exceptions/Handler` to change the unauthenticated user redirect url:

```
protected function unauthenticated($request, AuthenticationException $exception)
{
    if ($request->expectsJson()) {
        return response()->json(['error' => 'Unauthenticated.'], 401);
    }

    return redirect()->guest(route('login'));
}
```

But in `Laravel 5.5` this has been moved to this location `vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Exceptions/Handler.php` so how can I change it now? I don't want to change stuff in the vendor directory encase it gets overridden by composer updates.

```
protected function unauthenticated($request, AuthenticationException $exception)
{
    return $request->expectsJson()
                ? response()->json(['message' => 'Unauthenticated.'], 401)
                : redirect()->guest(route('login'));
}
```

Comment: https://laravel-news.com/custom-exception-reporting i found this

Comment: So you can catch the Authentication Error and then redirect before it gets caught by laravels. Nice thanks

Comment: @robertmylne is it working ? because this solution is just for reporting !!

Comment: @Maraboc it's not really doing what I had hoped it do. I was really hoping there was a place to override it.

Answer (score 70, accepted):

> But in Laravel 5.5 this has been moved to this location vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Exceptions/Handler.php so how can I change it now? I don't want to change stuff in the vendor directory encase it gets overridden by composer updates.

It's just the case that the function is not there by default anymore.

You can just override it as you did in 5.4. Just make sure to include

```
use Exception;
use Request;
use Illuminate\Auth\AuthenticationException;
use Response;
```

in the Handler file.

For Example my `app/Exceptions/Handler.php` looks somewhat like this:

```
<?php
    namespace App\Exceptions;
    use Exception;
    use Request;
    use Illuminate\Auth\AuthenticationException;
    use Response;
    use Illuminate\Foundation\Exceptions\Handler as ExceptionHandler;
    class Handler extends ExceptionHandler
    {
        (...) // The dfault file content
        /**
         * Convert an authentication exception into a response.
         *
         * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
         * @param  \Illuminate\Auth\AuthenticationException  $exception
         * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
         */
         protected function unauthenticated($request, AuthenticationException $exception)
         {
            return $request->expectsJson()
                    ? response()->json(['message' => 'Unauthenticated.'], 401)
                    : redirect()->guest(route('authentication.index'));
    }
}
```

Comment: Best answer I've found, thanks! Just one thing: is there a way instead of using expectsJson(), checking if the request was via the api route?

Comment: you are awesome men, i was thinking on disable the web middleware but this solution is best.

Comment: `if (in_array('api', \Route::getCurrentRoute()->computedMiddleware)) {
    return response()->json(['error' => 'Unauthenticated.'], 401);
}`

Comment: unauthenticated function in kernal.php is not present in version 5.7.

Comment: thank you so much, but I had to exchange the line response and redirect with each other, as I am having an api, in which i have a logout method, so in postman when i logged out the user after filling the header value like authorization = bearer plus access token generated by login, on first hit it logged out the user but if i clicked again, it says no message , and now its been replaced by json message : unauthenticated

Comment: Cleanest answer. Inside the unauthenticated method you could check for the guard: `$isWebGuard = method_exists($exception, 'guards') && in_array('web', $exception->guards());`. This way your responses are not tied up to the `expectsJson` method but to the guards that you specify, like `api` & `web`.

Answer (score 22):

Here's how I solved it. 
In render function I caught exception class. And in case if it's Authentication exception class I wrote my code for redirect (the code I would write in unauthenticated function in previous version).

```
public function render($request, Exception $exception)
{
    $class = get_class($exception);

    switch($class) {
        case 'Illuminate\Auth\AuthenticationException':
            $guard = array_get($exception->guards(), 0);
            switch ($guard) {
                case 'admin':
                    $login = 'admin.login';
                    break;
                default:
                    $login = 'login';
                    break;
            }

            return redirect()->route($login);
    }

    return parent::render($request, $exception);
}
```

Comment: thanks it worked for me. i used DevMarketer MultiAuth tutorial in youtube but it seems it's not working in laravel 5.5. this solve my problem.

Comment: worked with me 2, and i am suing devMarketer...world is too small

Comment: Working on this same issue. When you got this to work, did you use the stock Laravel 5.5 function for `unauthenticated`? Or did you also include the version of the `unauthenticated` function from 5.4?

Comment: Have tried this code, but `$exception->guards()` always returns nothing for me, so I have nothing to test against. If you have any additional resources you could recommend for a solution, it would be appreciated. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: it still gives me this ```Route [login] not defined.```

Answer (score 7):

> But in Laravel 5.5 this has been moved to this location
>   vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Exceptions/Handler.php
>   so how can I change it now? I don't want to change stuff in the vendor
>   directory encase it gets overridden by composer updates.

We need to just include the 
use Illuminate\Auth\AuthenticationException;

and then it works as in laravel 5.4

Comment: Thanks, this solution is work for me in Laravel 5.5 :)

Answer (score 5):

**For Laravel ( 5.4, 6, 7, 8.x )**

> I don't want to change in the vendor directory **encase it gets
> overridden by composer updates**. You can just override it as you did
> in 5.4. Just make sure to include.

**File: App\Exceptions\Handler.php**

*Copy this below `code` and past to your `app\Exception\Handler`*

```
<?php

namespace App\Exceptions;

use Request;
use Illuminate\Auth\AuthenticationException;
use Response;

use Illuminate\Support\Arr;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Exceptions\Handler as ExceptionHandler;
use Throwable;

class Handler extends ExceptionHandler
{
    /**
     * A list of the exception types that are not reported.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $dontReport = [
        //
    ];

    /**
     * A list of the inputs that are never flashed for validation exceptions.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $dontFlash = [
        'password',
        'password_confirmation',
    ];

    /**
     * Report or log an exception.
     *
     * @param  \Throwable  $exception
     * @return void
     *
     * @throws \Exception
     */
    public function report(Throwable $exception)
    {
        parent::report($exception);
    }

    /**
     * Render an exception into an HTTP response.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Throwable  $exception
     * @return \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response
     *
     * @throws \Throwable
     */
    public function render($request, Throwable $exception)
    {
        return parent::render($request, $exception);
    }
        protected function unauthenticated($request, AuthenticationException $exception)
    {
        // return $request->expectsJson()
        //             ? response()->json(['message' => $exception->getMessage()], 401)
        //             : redirect()->guest(route('login'));

        if($request->expectsJson()) {
            return response()->json(['message' =>  $exception->getMessage()],401);
        }

        $guard = Arr::get($exception->guards(), 0);

        switch ($guard) {
            case 'admin':
            $login = 'admin.login';
            break;
            case 'vendor':
            $login = 'vendor.login';
            break;
            
            default:
            $login = 'login';
            break;
        }

        return redirect()->guest(route($login));

    }
}
```

Comment: Worked like a charm in `8.29.0`. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

The standard exception handler uses a named route.

So, you just define your route to use that name.

So, in your `routes/web.php` file, just add the line:

```
Route::get('mylogin', 'MyLoginController@showLoginForm')->name('login');
```

The `name('login')` bit gives this route a name, so the unauthenticated exception will use this route.

You don't need to bother messing around making your own exception handler, or modifying the standard exception handler.

The named routes used by the boilerplate 'auth' code can be found in the `vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php` file, in the `auth()` function. (login, logout, register, password.request, password.email and password.reset). These routes are added when you use the `Route::auth();` line in the route file.

Comment: Thanks for a simple solution to the problem, I don't know why nobody else has upvoted this, this solved the issue for me, and the complex answers actually didn't even work at all.

Comment: This helped me alot

Answer (score 1):

In newer versions of Laravel, you should go to

> app/Http/Middleware/Authenticate.php

Now you can edit the function and redirect it to wherever you want:

```
protected function redirectTo($request)
{
    if (! $request->expectsJson()) {
        return route('login');
    }
}
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Just add a route for login in routes file:

```
Route::get('/login', [
   'uses' => 'UserController@getSignin',
   'as' => 'login'
]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace Your app\Exceptions\Handler.php  code with the following....

```
<?php

namespace App\Exceptions;

use Exception;
use Illuminate\Auth\AuthenticationException;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Exceptions\Handler as ExceptionHandler;

class Handler extends ExceptionHandler
{
    /**
     * A list of the exception types that are not reported.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $dontReport = [
        //
    ];

    /**
     * A list of the inputs that are never flashed for validation exceptions.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $dontFlash = [
        'password',
        'password_confirmation',
    ];

    /**
     * Report or log an exception.`enter code here`
     *
     * @param  \Exception  $exception
     * @return void
     */
    public function report(Exception $exception)
    {
        parent::report($exception);
    }

    /**
     * Render an exception into an HTTP response.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Exception  $exception
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function render($request, Exception $exception)
    {
        return parent::render($request, $exception);
    }

    protected function unauthenticated($request, AuthenticationException $exception)
    {
        if ($request->expectsJson()) {
            return response()->json(['message' => $exception->getMessage()], 401);
        }


        $guard = array_get($exception->guards(),0);
        switch ($guard) {
            case 'admin':
                $login = 'admin.login';
                break;

            default:
                $login = 'login';
                break;
        }

        return redirect()->guest(route($login));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**`Copy this to your app\Exception\Handler`**

```
use Request;
use Illuminate\Auth\AuthenticationException;
use Response;

protected function unauthenticated($request, AuthenticationException $exception){
  if ($request->expectsJson()) {
     return response()->json(['message' => $exception->getMessage()], 401);
  }

  $guard = array_get($exception->guards(),0);

  switch ($guard) {
    case 'admin':
        return redirect()->guest(route('admin.login'));
       break;

     default:
       return redirect()->guest(route('login'));
      break;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**For Laravel 7.x+**

```
===========**top add class:**================
use Illuminate\Auth\AuthenticationException;

use Illuminate\Support\Arr;
=======================================

public function render($request, Throwable $exception)
    {
        if($exception instanceof AuthenticationException){
            $guard = Arr::get($exception->guards(), 0);
            switch($guard){
                case 'admin':
                    return redirect(route('admin.login'));
                    break;
                default:
                    return redirect(route('login'));
                    break;
            }
        }

        return parent::render($request, $exception);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

For Laravel verison 7.*

File: App\Exceptions\Handler.php

use Illuminate\Support\Arr; //Top Class

use Illuminate\Foundation\Exceptions\Handler as ExceptionHandler;

public function render($request, Throwable $exception)
    {

```
    // for Multi AUth guard

    if($exception instanceof AuthenticationException){
        $guard = Arr::get($exception->guards(), 0);
        switch($guard){
            case 'admin':
                return redirect(route('admin.login'));
                break;
            default:
                return redirect(route('login'));
                break;
        }
    }



    return parent::render($request, $exception);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Other than `overriding`, you could directly make changes in `Handler.php` to the existing function **unauthenticated** located at `vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Exceptions/Handler.php` to redirect to intended route based on guards.

```
/**
 * Convert an authentication exception into a response.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @param  \Illuminate\Auth\AuthenticationException  $exception
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
protected function unauthenticated($request, AuthenticationException $exception)
{


    $guard = array_get($exception->guards(),0);
    switch ($guard) {
        case 'admin':
            return $request->expectsJson()
                        ? response()->json(['message' => $exception->getMessage()], 401)
                        : redirect()->guest(route('admin.login'));
            break;

        default:
            return $request->expectsJson()
                        ? response()->json(['message' => $exception->getMessage()], 401)
                        : redirect()->guest(route('login'));
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm working on a multiple authentication system, and I've been trying to get this to work, but when this exception is thrown, `$exception->guards()` is coming back as empty for me. Do you know of any reason why the guards would not be available? I'm working in Laravel 5.5.40, and have been trying to implement multiple guards for authenticating different users. I'm working off of the video series on 'Multi-Auth' by devmarketer.

Comment: making changes in the vendor folder directly is highly bad practice! you should never ever do this

Answer (score -14):

1.Go to `vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Exceptions/Handler.php` file.

2.Search the method name is `unauthenticated`.

3.And change the redirect url from
 `redirect()->guest(route('login'))` to `redirect()->guest(route('api/login')) //whatever you want`.

You could return the response as a JSON if it is API services.

Comment: It is very bad practice to make changes in files from external packages! Don't do this.

Comment: to ellaborate on @thephper's answer:

if you make changes to external packages they will be lost if you ever update them.

Comment: If you want to lose all of your code by running a composer update command, use this!!

Comment: Nothing will impact if you are running the composer update command. In laravel, they are having certain level of security while accessing the API or Routes services.

Comment: https://medium.com/@shyammakwana/laravel-how-to-override-vendor-class-file-52c7d7b3b384

Comment: making changes in the vendor folder directly is highly bad practice! you should never ever do this

Comment: This is the biggest mistake you could ever do!