# Laravel 5.5 - After upgrading auth is not redirecting properly

Tags: authentication, laravel-5

I just upgraded my application from Laravel 5.4 to v 5.5.  Non authenticated users are not redirecting properly now.

Normally a non authenticated user should be redirected to **/manage/login** but it is redirected to **/login** route.

Everything was working perfect in Laravel v 5.4

My app contain two guards.

Routing in `web.php`

```
Auth::routes();
Route::middleware(['auth:manager'])->group(function () {

    Route::get('/manage', 'Manage\AdminController@dashboard')->name('manage.home');

});
```

So before upgrade a non authenticated user trying to access **/manage** was redirected to **/manage/login** but after upgrading it is redirecting to **/login**.

I have Auth Controllers copied and modified as needed in Manage\Auth.
Similarly Views are in folder structure Manage\Auth.

My LoginController in Controllers\Manage\Auth

|

```
 Login Controller
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This controller handles authenticating users for the application and
    | redirecting them to your home screen. The controller uses a trait
    | to conveniently provide its functionality to your applications.
    |
    */

    use AuthenticatesUsers;

    /**
    * Where to redirect users after login.
    *
    * @var string
    */
    protected $redirectTo = '/manage/';

    /**
    * Create a new controller instance.
    *
    * @return void
    */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest')->except('logout');
    }
    public function showLoginForm()
    {
        return view('manage.auth.login');
    }
    public function logout(Request $request)
    {
        $this->guard()->logout();
        $request->session()->flush();
        $request->session()->regenerate();
        return redirect('/manage');
    }
    protected function guard()
    {
        return Auth::guard('manager');
    }
```

Comment: Try adding a named route called `login` to your routes which points to `App\Http\Controllers\Auth\LoginController@showLoginForm` with a path of `manage/login`

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same problem, and it's quit simple to solve.

the point is that if you are using **guards** you were probably handling unauthenticated exception in your `app/Exceptions/Handler.php` . when using laravel 5.4 .

After update to 5.5 this is done under `vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Exceptions/Handler.php` .

You should refer to this [Laravel 5.5 change unauthenticated login redirect url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45340855/laravel-5-5-change-unauthenticated-login-redirect-url) for more details about how to solve it.