# Changing redirect url for login in laravel 5.6.3

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravel-5.6

I installed the adminlte theme and I want to create an admin area. 
So my url should look like :

```
/admin =  admin home page dashboard
/admin/login
/admin/register/
```

This is my route so far:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth'], function () {
    Route::get('/admin', ['as' => 'admin', 'uses' => 'Admin\DashboardController@index']);
});
```

When I access the `/admin` page I am redirected to `/login` instead of `/admin/login`

The redirection is made from here:

```
vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Exceptions/Handler.php
```

in the `unauthenticated` method

I followed up the answer from here: [Laravel 5.5 change unauthenticated login redirect url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45340855/laravel-5-5-change-unauthenticated-login-redirect-url) ,but i ended up with this error:

```
Declaration of App\Exceptions\Handler::unauthenticated($request, App\Exceptions\AuthenticationException $exception) should be compatible with Illuminate\Foundation\Exceptions\Handler::unauthenticated($request, Illuminate\Auth\AuthenticationException $exception)
```

Any idea how do I change my redirect url ?  Thank you

Comment: Actually you dont have route for /admin/login, you have route for /login if you are using default auth of the laravel.

Answer (score 2):

Actually you dont have route `/admin/login`. 
In your `routes\web.php` file, create route as

```
// Authentication Routes...
$this->get('admin/login', 'Auth\LoginController@showLoginForm')->name('login');
```

And after this update the default redirect route for unauthorized users as follows

In `app/Exceptions/Handler.php`

```
 protected function unauthenticated($request, AuthenticationException $exception)
    {
        if ($request->expectsJson()) {
            return response()->json(['error' => 'Unauthenticated.'], 401);
        }

        return redirect()->guest('/admin/login');
    }
```

Correct location to update : `app/Exceptions/Handler.php`

**Another way where you can just attache prefix on your routes:**
Update the file `app/providers/RouteServiceProvider.php` as

```
protected function mapWebRoutes()
    {
        Route::prefix('admin/')
             ->middleware('web')
             ->namespace($this->namespace)
             ->group(base_path('routes/web.php'));
    }
```

Please notice `Route::prefix('admin/')`, now doing this you should have routes like

```
Route::get('/', function () {......
Route::get('/login', function () {.....
```

Now you are just attaching prefix on routes not changing the routes anywhere on tha laravel application. This might be better to do.

Comment: Hi, I don't have `Auth::routes();` this part , I posted all of the content of my `web.php` file, I added the login part that you suggested and the function , but right now I am not anymore redirected and I am getting a lovely blank page on the /admin

Comment: okay not problem, the point is you should have route defined for `admin/login` and you should have updated Handler.php. Andother method is to defining prefix. let me update my answer for prefix.

Comment: I got the blank page , cuz of a syntax error. Fixed that, now I am getting this: `Declaration of App\Exceptions\Handler::unauthenticated($request, App\Exceptions\AuthenticationException $exception) should be compatible with Illuminate\Foundation\Exceptions\Handler::unauthenticated($request, Illuminate\Auth\AuthenticationException $exception)` , BUT i am not redirected to /login or /admin/login

Comment: use `Exception` instead of `AuthenticationException ` on `app/Exceptions/Handler.php`  and see if works

Comment: Keep AuthenticationException as it is and include AuthenticationException in Handler.php by using code : use Illuminate\Auth\AuthenticationException;. This worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

in vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Exceptions/Handler.php

update function authentication

```
 /**
 * Convert an authentication exception into a response.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @param  \Illuminate\Auth\AuthenticationException  $exception
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
protected function unauthenticated($request, AuthenticationException $exception)
{
    if($request->expectsJson()){
        return response()->json(['message' => $exception->getMessage()], 401);

    }

    $guard = array_get($exception->guards(),0);

    switch ($guard) {
        case 'admin':
            return redirect()->guest(route('admin.login'));
            break;

        default:
            return redirect()->guest(route('login'));
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: then with the next composer update , my code will be updated ;)