# How to prevent an error on undefined routes in Laravel 5.5

Tags: laravel-5

I developed an API with Laravel 5.5. All is working fine.

But imagine that a user enter an "api" url directly in the browser (for example: api/books), then they will receive an error:

```
InvalidArgumentException
Route [login] not defined.
```

How to prevent this? I tried to add some routes in the routes/web.php file, but without success.

Or perhaps I should do nothing (there will be very few users who will do that)?

Comment: Api urls are open. So, nothing to hide at first, anyone can directly access that. Apis that need authenticated users should contain a token in header or in url parameter. So, you can check the accessing url contains the token. If it's not then you can throw error.

Comment: Hi Sovon. I would rather look for a solution like "if the route is not found in the file routes/web.php, then redirect to an information page". It is what I am trying to do. The solution that you speak about seems to me more complex. No ?

Comment: It's not complex to me. Anyway, you can't check the route list in one file like web.php. You can add prefix to all your api routes and check your route contain that prefix. But again in that way you are restricting calls from other devices as well. Because directly entering from browser or calling it from mobile are the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer here:

[Laravel 5.5 change unauthenticated login redirect url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45340855/laravel-5-5-change-unauthenticated-login-redirect-url)

I only do that in the "app/Exceptions/Handler.php" file, I modified the function "render" like that :

```
public function render($request, Exception $exception)
{
    // return parent::render($request, $exception);
    
    // add dom
    return redirect('/');
    
    // or redirection with a json
    /*
    return response()->json(
        [
            'errors' => [
                'status' => 401,
                'message' => 'Unauthenticated',
            ]
        ], 401
    );
    */
}
```

And it works fine. As the "Laravel" part will be used only as back end for APIs, it will be enough.