# Implementing native multi auth (user vs admin) using guards in Laravel 5.5 - guest middle ware uses hard coded named route

Tags: laravel, authentication, laravel-5, laravel-5.5, auth-guard

I would like to implement native multi authentication in my application for two types of users: **User** and **Admin**.

1. I started implementing a new `admins` table migration (by copying the existing create_users_table).
2. I created a new model called **Admin** (by copying the existing *User* model)
3. Both (*User* and *Admin*) models were updated to specify which guards they use like this:

**User** Model

```
protected $guarded  = ['user'];
```

**Admin** Model

```
protected $guarded  = ['admin'];
```

4. Then I setup the auth configuration like this:

**config/auth.php**

https://pastebin.com/iLAZbX2z

5. Then I defined my custom auth routes for `users` and `admins` like this:

**routes/web.php**

https://pastebin.com/raw/CKX9Xddb

6. Finally, I defined the auth protected routes for the two user types like this:

**routes/web.php**

```
// User auth protected pages
Route::prefix('manage')->middleware('auth:user')->namespace('Manage')->group(function() {

    Route::get('/', 'DashboardController@index');

});

// Admin auth protected pages
Route::prefix('admin')->middleware('auth:admin')->namespace('Admin')->group(function() {

    Route::get('/', 'DashboardController@index');

});
```

I tested the user login first before proceeding (there's more to be done to get admin to login), by going into http://myapp.local/login and entering my credentials and I was successfully redirected to user's dashboard (i.e. http://myapp.local/manage). All of the user specific functionality (e.g. reset pass) etc.. are all working fine).

However; when testing the guest middleware by visiting `http://myapp.local/manage` directly, I expected to be redirected to `http://myapp.local/login` but got an error instead:

> Route [login] not defined.

This error is valid; because in the routes definition, I've named the user login as `user.login`

It looks like the `guest` middleware uses a hard coded named route called `login` in the unauthenticated exception handler.

**vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Exceptions\Handler.php**

```
protected function unauthenticated($request, AuthenticationException $exception)
{
    return $request->expectsJson()
                ? response()->json(['message' => $exception->getMessage()], 401)
                : redirect()->guest(route('login')); // <------
}
```

How can I tell the guest middleware to use a differently named route for the login (when un-authenticated user tries to visit a auth protected page)?

I will need to use this later for the admin guest middleware also.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to `Sohel0415`'s answer; I realised that the `App\Exceptions\Handler` extends the `vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Exceptions\Handler.php`, which means I can solve it like this:

I've edited the `app\Exceptions\Handler.php` like this:

1. Included this `use` statement at the top:

> use Illuminate\Auth\AuthenticationException;

2. Added this method:

https://pastebin.com/raw/10Y1tS6d

Answer (score 0):

> I've named the user login as `user.login`

You're getting the error because the route name is `user.login` and you're trying to use `login` route. So, use proper route name here:

```
redirect()->guest(route('user.login'));
```

Comment: I am not trying to use the `redirect()->guest(route('login'));` - that's what the framework comes with, the line i posted above was taken from: `vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Exceptions\Handler.php` hence why i said the named route is hard coded and I am trying to find a way to override it.

Answer (score 0):

Use `Request::is()` to `check` the `requested url`, then redirect :

```
protected function unauthenticated($request, AuthenticationException $exception)
{
      if(\Request::is('manage/*')){
      return $request->expectsJson()
            ? response()->json(['message' => $exception->getMessage()], 401)
            : redirect()->guest(route('user.login'));
      }
      else if(\Request::is('admin/*')){
        return $request->expectsJson()
            ? response()->json(['message' => $exception->getMessage()], 401)
            : redirect()->guest(route('admin.login'));
      }
      else{
        return $request->expectsJson()
            ? response()->json(['message' => $exception->getMessage()], 401)
            : redirect()->guest(route('login'));
      }
}
```

**Note:** add this method in `App\Exceptions\Handler`

Comment: Are you saying i need to override the exception handler? if so, how and where?

Comment: you can follow this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28702372/how-to-change-default-redirect-url-of-laravel-5-auth-filter

Comment: thanks for the update; it gave me an idea to solve it slightly differently. See my answer.

Comment: nice one, +1 :)